# CouchDB View Empty space in search

Tags: javascript, view, couchdb

I am trying to search in couchDb using temporary view in futon.

The view code is like this:

```
function(doc)
 {
  if(doc.Time Zone.value == "America/Los_Angeles")
  { 
   emit([doc.owner, doc.source], null); 
  }
 }
```

But when I try to sun this view, it give the following error:
Error: compilation_error

Expression does not eval to a function. ((new String("function(doc) { if(doc.Time Zone.value == \"America/Los_Angeles\") { emit([doc.owner, doc.source], null); }  }")))

I think this is because of a space in doc.Time Zone. If a remove this space it compiles but didn't give any values. Compiler dont want this empty space.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the way you access your document's *Time Zone*  field is invalid.

The proper way to access that field would be

```js
doc['Time Zone'].value
```

It is a basic JavaScript issue you're facing.

Comment: I tried this - function(doc) { if(doc['Time Zone'].value' == "America/Los_Angeles") { emit([doc.owner, doc.source], null); }  } Still getting this error:-Error: compilation_error

Expression does not eval to a function. ((new String("function(doc) { if(doc['Time Zone'].value' == \"America/Los_Angeles\") { emit([doc.owner, doc.source], null); }  }")))

Comment: `if(doc['Time Zone'].value' == "America/Los_Angeles")`  <- note trailing quote after `value`, it shouldn't be there

Comment: Thanks a lot Kxepal and Octavian Damiean